# Small FPS with Background Image

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a big problem with my app.
I am few steps before the end of my app and today I wanted to add a background image.
My normal FPS is 180 during black background and when I added my background for iphone 4 sized 960/640 my FPS changed to 20-30 so its impossible to play. And next thing what happens is, when my player and enemy has a collision they stop their actions, but only if there is my background. I am using SpaceManager so maybe its because of its shapes. So does anyone know how to add background in another way in SpaceManager to do not slow my FPS? Here is the way I try to add Background:

```
-(id) init
{
CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Background.png"];

background.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);

[self addChild:background z:-1];
}
```

Comment: could this performance issue have to do with the way you deal collisions? are you also including the background when checking for collisions?

Comment: is this FPS drop measured on a device ? Simulator figures are meaningless.

Comment: Its on the device but its from a bigger part solved but now I have a problem with the collision, each collision stop all actions.

Comment: need more details, the background itself can't be an issue. If you get 180 fps you're not testing on a device (60 Hz max.) or you're reading the wrong value as fps (bottom-most is fps)

Comment: are you using CCSpriteBatchNode?

Comment: I had 180 on simulator, 30 with BG, on device 60 and 30 with BG, for Background I use the code above with the ccsprite..

Comment: well, assume you were running (before the BG) at 15 ms per draw cycle, you would get 60 FPS. Now, if the draw call for the background adds a mere 3-4 ms to complete, your FPS will drop to 30 (there is NO in between). Again, as Learned Cocos2D suggests, need more info :).

Comment: ignore Simulator. Are your other sprites batched? What version of cocos2d? Which device?

Comment: Okey, so the version is 2.1, all of my sprites are cpCCSprites and the background is CCSprite I have never batched any sprite so I dont think this could be the problem, but could you give me there short code of code how to add this code above as CCspritebatch... and I test it on 3.5inch iPhone = iphone 4..

Comment: Ok, I batched all files and now I am at 32 fps I dont care now about it.. so I just want to know, where is the problem, that if there is any collision it stops all actions of that object?

Comment: one batch for all (most) sprites? what does the topmost number (draw calls) in the 3-lines in the lower left say? Can't say anything about collisions without seeing your collision detection code. I can imagine that you inadvertently check collision against the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the most likely cause for the drop in fps is because the picture is designed for the retina display, and since it is a large file it slows down the app. the device which you are using also has an effect on how fast the game works, so if its slow only on a 3gs or something like that just drop support for it.

Comment: I make this game just for iphones and for 3gs I have different files The problem is with 4, 5 .. still cant find solution.

Comment: well is 30 fps really that bad because in many games ive played on computer (mine craft) 30 fps is very good and it runs smoothly

Comment: This game is about football so the enemy reactions must be pretty fast so it because I must have there schedulers on 0.1second so 30 fps is not enough and next thing the shape collision in Spacemanager stops all actions of the sprite so Dont you know the solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

So my Objects are statit mass, so I dont have there [sm addcollision] but I have there this code

```
-(void) KolizeHraceSProtiHracem
{
if (player.position.x - enemy.position.x < 40 )
{

[enemy stopAllActions];
[player stopAllActions];


[player runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.2 position:ccp(player.position.x + 40, 10)]];

[enemy runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.1 position:ccp(enemy.position.x - 10, 10)]];
}
```

I dont think, this code is bad, because if I dont have a background this code works but if i do this code stops all actions.